# What is the difference between these two nloglog(n) sorting algorithms? (Andersson et al., 1995 vs. Han, 2004)

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, sorting, complexity-theory

Swanepoel's comment [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2340/what-is-the-first-interesting-theorem-in-insert-subject-here/2342#2342) lead me to [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jalgor.2003.09.001). Then, searching for an implementation in C, I came across [this](http://www.nada.kth.se/~snilsson/public/code/nloglogn.c), which referenced [another paper](http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/225058.225173) on an algorithm described [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/184404062/).

Both papers describe integer sorting algorithms that run in O(nloglog(n)) time. What is the difference between the two? Have there been any more recent findings about this topic?

[Andersson et al., 1995](http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/225058.225173)

[Han, 2004](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jalgor.2003.09.001)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the abstract of the Han Paper:

> This also improves previous best
>   deterministic sorting algorithm [A.
>   Andersson, T. Hagerup, S. Nilsson, R.
>   Raman, in: Proc. 1995 Symposium on
>   Theory of Computing (1995) 427–436; Y.
>   Han, X. Shen, in: Proc. 1995
>   International Computing and
>   Combinatorics Conference, in: Lecture
>   Notes in Comput. Sci. 959 (1995)
>   324–333] which sorts in O(nloglogn)
>   time but uses O(m^e) space. Our results
>   also improves the result of Andersson
>   et al. [A. Andersson, T. Hagerup, S.
>   Nilsson, R. Raman, in: Proc. 1995
>   Symposium on Theory of Computing
>   (1995) 427–436] which sorts in
>   O(nloglogn) time and linear space but
>   uses randomization.

So there are two Anderson et al papers. One uses O(m^e) space and other uses randomization, but linear space. Han paper is deterministic with linear space.